# Get a reference of the ApplicationServiceDescriptor instance being used to generate FederationMetadata.xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, wif, federation

Following up on [a question I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020091/set-claimtypesrequested-in-organizational-accounts-on-premises-federation), and with the assumption that ASP.NET MVC5 generates the `FederationMetadata.xml` file dynamically (probably through code like [this](http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/category/windows-identity-foundation/)), I'd like to know whether I can get a reference to the instance of `ApplicationServiceDescriptor` so I could alter the `FederationMetadata.xml` being generated. If that's not possible, is there a way to stop this mechanism altogether and replace it with custom code? Like a different `FederationMetadata.xml` file provider or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know MVC5.  In MVC4 we just generate the metadata document ourselves using a controller that is linked to a

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "FederationMetaData",
                url: "FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
                defaults: new
                          {
                              controller = "FederationMetadata",
                              action = "GenerateMetaData"
                          }
                );
```

IMHO you probably just need to install your controller to handle the route.